# ResultSet getDouble giving incorrect values

Tags: jdbc

1) I have a Sybase database which contains a table say 'TABLE1'. One of the fields say 'X' (which in business terms represents money), has type 'float' in that table. UNFORTUNATELY, I can not change the type of this column because many applications will be affected if I do the same.

2) I am using jconn2.jar in JDBC. I retrieve 'X' by using getDouble()( I read somewhere that the float,double SQL types are best mapped as double 'java data type' ).

3) The value stored in 'X' in the database is '212400000'. When I do a getDouble(int col), I get '212399999.99999997' (in the scientific form). I am loosing precision. I am aware of the fact that there are certain numbers which can not be represented exactly in base 2 and hence we see some incorrect outputs while using double.

4) I have tried getBigDecimal but in vain. I am stuck. Could some one guide me through the same ?

EDIT:- 
One question which I need to ask is that is there a way where in I can use getDouble() to retrieve a value based on the precision I need say 12,17 etc ? What is the default precision associated with getDouble() ?

Comment: What precision have you specified for your float field? What's *creating* the data? (It could be that it's accurately representing the data in the database, and whatever you're using to see it as 212400000 is just rounding to a smaller number of significant digits.)

Comment: Another application is creating the data with a precision of 24 (c++ code). But my doubt was if the implementation of getDouble() in a Sybase result set is creating the difference. Had the SQL type been DECIMAL/MONEY and the java equivalent being BigDecimal, would we have still seen the same scenario ?

Comment: It would depend what the actual value was in the database. I suspect you really *are* getting the value that's in there, and that the error crept in much earlier. But you still haven't told us what the *field* precision is - the precision of the C++ code inserting the data isn't the same thing as the precision of storage.

Comment: Please write some code and also table structure of the table.

Comment: @JonSkeet - 1) Apologies for writing late. With my little knowledge of Database, I can say that the field has a precision of 0. I confirmed this from the table creation script(someone else wrote that some years ago). Also when I do a resultSet.getMetadata().getPrecision(), I see this column's precision value as zero. 2)Jon, I buy your first point, having said that as I mentioned that the precision of this column in database is 0, the c++ code inserting a value is using a precision of 24 (again, the column is float).