# Wrong value returned by the ResultSet for Oracle database

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, resultset

I am facing a strange issue with JDBC such that the value of a numeric and date field in the DB is different from the value returned by the `ResultSet`.

I have the following row in the database (showing only 3 columns related to the question)

```
J_ID       J_DATE              J_AMOUNT
1          29-JAN-16           2.339549839
```

I am using standard JDBC to fetch this row from the DB as follows :

```
while (rs.next()) {
   System.out.println(rs.getDouble("J_AMOUNT"));
   Timestamp ts = rs.getTimestamp("J_DATE");
   Date d = ts != null ? new java.util.Date(ts.getTime()) : null;
   System.out.println(d);
}
```

The output is :

`2.345773196
Thu Mar 31 00:00:00 IST 2016`

I am scratching my head trying to figure out why *2.339549839* was read as *2.345773196* by `getDouble` and why *29-JAN-16* was converted to *Thu Mar 31 00:00:00 IST 2016* by the `getDate` method.

I am using Oracle database and`odbc5.jar`. I found a related question but it does not seem to have any answers and the comments don't answer my question as well :

1. [ResultSet getDouble giving incorrect values.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10493397/resultset-getdouble-giving-incorrect-values).
2. [ResultSet.getInt return wrong value](http://www.coderanch.com/t/547775/JDBC/databases/ResultSet-getInt-return-wrong)
3. [Wrong long value from ResultSet.getTimeStamp().getTime()](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2049451?start=0&tstart=0)

I am obviously doing something wrong but not sure what it could be since this is a pretty basic program.

**Additional info :**

1. The query being executed to fetch the result set as logged by my program is as follows :

   `SELECT B.J_ID, B.J_DATE, ROUND(B.J_AMOUNT, 9) FROM REF.J_MESSAGES B WHERE B.J_ID = 1`
2. The value of the `J_DATE` field when converted to time

   `SELECT B.J_ID, to_char(B.J_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as J_DATE, ROUND(B.J_AMOUNT, 9) FROM REF.J_MESSAGES B WHERE B.J_ID = 1`

   `J_ID       J_DATE                        J_AMOUNT
   1          2016-01-29 00:00:00           2.339549839`
3. Using `getString` instead of `getDouble` and `getTimeStamp` gives the following output :

   `2.345773196
   2016-03-31 00:00:00.0`
4. I am using SQL developer to manually execute the query on my oracle database and I have confirmed that I am hitting the right DB, schema, table and Oracle instance in Java as well as in SQL developer.
5. Here is a describe on my table (Only listing the columns related to this question) :

   ```
      Name              Null     Type          

      J_DATE                     DATE  
      J_AMOUNT                   NUMBER(30,14)
   ```
6. JDBC driver version is :
   `JDBC driver version is 11.1.0.6.0-Production+`
7. I created my own table with only 2 columns (J_DATE and J_AMOUNT) and this issue was reproducible on this table as well so it's not likely that this may be some kind of a sync issue where the table is read while being updated by another system.

Comment: Try getting the values as strings, to examine what they are. rs.getString()

Comment: Have you checked to see if those values match anywhere in your database table in the first place, this will make sure that it is not a data issue. Make sure that RS is only being referenced from one querey and not multiple ones as that will distort data

Comment: @scarecrow- Good point. I have spent hours on this issue and this is one of the things I did check myself. The value is not present in the DB table for any of the numeric columns and I have confirmed that I am selecting the same table in the query.

Comment: looks like the formatting of your tables time may not coincide with the constructor of getTimeStamp.

Comment: Have you also checked that you don't have uncommitted changes in the session you're seeing 29-Jan; and (less likely, from the checks you've already done) that you're connected to the same DB and schema, not just seeing a similar table somewhere else?

Comment: @SualehFatehi This is something I haven't tried. Will try this out as soon as I get access to my office PC again.

Comment: @AlexPoole Valid point. Both these checks have been taken care of as well. I don't have write access to these tables and I had added logs to confirm that I am hitting the right DB and table.

Comment: Just to humour me... can you edit the question to add the actual statement being executed over JDBC to get your result set? And also show the table's J_DATE value with its time (`to_char(j_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'`)? I'm sure I'm wrong but it's making me suspicious *8-)

Comment: @AlexPoole Apologies for the delay,. Had to get access to my work machine to post what you requested. Check it out and let me know if it helps.

Comment: @SualehFatehi Please see the ouput using `getString` instead of `getDouble` and `getDate`.

Comment: maybe you can post a sql table definition so we can be sure that the data types are ok in oracle? Also is there any reason not to try with some other jdbc driver to be sure it's not driver issue?

Comment: Which version of the Oracle JDBC driver are you using? And no, ojdbc5 is not a version, it just means the library is for Java 5/JDBC3.

Comment: @Nadir Posted the same. Please check.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Updated the question with this information. Please check point 6 in additional info section.

Comment: why you need 14 digits after decimal? As it is an amount field 2 digits after decimal is sufficient.

Comment: @AmitRaj This is beyond the scope of the question. This is the schema that our system uses and we need to adhere to it. Also, the data in the database flows down from a different system and we are simply the consumers of this data. Besides, why should only 2 decimal places suffice for an amount field? Financial transactions can go as high as 9 decimal places.

Comment: Add `J_ID` to select and output its value. What it will be?

Comment: @Andremoniy `rs.getString("J_ID");` prints `1`. Not adding this to the question to avoid cluttering it.

Comment: @user6043279 Just out of curiosity, is the driver a jdbc type 1 (JDBC-ODBC bridge) or jdbc type 4 driver? And also your OS?